# Basic installation of a package on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

When I type ndiswrapper -l, I get the output:

```
The program 'ndiswrapper' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common
```

However, when I run that command, I get:

```
"ndiswrapper-common is already the newest version"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like apt got confused. Try to remove ndiswrapper-common, updating your cache and trying again:

```
sudo dpkg -P ndiswrapper-common
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common
```

Comment: on the -P command, I get this: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of ndiswrapper-common

Comment: perhaps a mutual dependency on ndiswrapper-utils?

Comment: which had a dependency on ndisgtk.

Comment: Doing a bit of digging, I was able to correctly remove the dependent packages in the correct order, then run the commands as you suggested.